# '(dynamic) => dynamic' is not a subtype of type '(Node) >= bool'

Tags: dart, dynamic, where-clause

I'm getting this error

> **Unhandled exception: type '(dynamic) => dynamic' is not a subtype of type '(Node) => bool' of 'test'**

when is trying to do this line:

```
element.nodes.where((n) => n.nodes.isNotEmpty)
```

I've tried to execute with evaluation expression for every element.node and it works well, so no idea what it can be.

**Block of code**

```
...
void method(var elements){
...
var elements = _document.querySelectorAll(section_class);

for (var element in elements) {
  for (var node
         in element.nodes.where((n) => n.nodes.isNotEmpty)) {
...
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that it was defined var for local variables as well as method arguments, so the compiler didn't know which type the children were.

So, define var in small scopes instead of massively use it for everything.